# $H(\kappa)$-absoluteness of a formula

Tags: set-theory

Let $\varphi(x,y)$ be an $\in$-formula which is absolute between transitive models of ZF minus powerset axiom. Then $\exists x\, \varphi(x,y)$ is $H(\kappa)$-absolute, where $H(\kappa)$ is the set $\{x\, |\, card(TC(\{x\}))<\kappa\}$. $\kappa$ is uncountable regular.

This is a homework question and I would prefer a hint instead of a solution.

Comment: Precisely what does "$\psi(y)$ is $H(\kappa)$-absolute" mean?

Comment: This means that, for any $y\in H(\kappa)$, $\psi(y)$ holds in V iff it holds in $H(\kappa)$. So in this case the task is to show that $x$ can be chosen in $H(\kappa)$ if such a x exists in V.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\kappa$ is regular?

Comment: No, $\kappa$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I just realized I made a mistake in the question. $\varphi$ should be absolute between models of ZF minus powerset (which includes $H(\kappa)$ for uncountable $\kappa$). Also, $\kappa$ should indeed be uncountable regular. Sorry for all that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming ZFC in $V$. Since $\kappa$ is uncountable regular, $H(\kappa)$ models all axioms of ZFC except powerset. (*)

The relativization of $\exists x \, \varphi(x,y)$ to $H(\kappa)$ is $\exists x\in H(\kappa) \,\varphi(x,y)$, $\varphi$ is absolute between $V$ and $H(\kappa)$ because of (*). So it needs to be shown that, if for some $y\in H(\kappa)$ there is $x\in V$ with $\varphi(x,y)$, then there is $x\in H(\kappa)$ with $\varphi(x,y)$.

For $y\in H(\kappa)$, let $T_y:=TC(\{y\})\subseteq H(\kappa)$ with $|T_y|<\kappa$. Let $\kappa'\geq \kappa$ regular be so that if there is $x\in V$ with $\varphi(x,y)$, there is $x\in H(\kappa')$ with $\varphi(x,y)$. Let $S_y$ be a Skolem hull of $T_y$ in $H(\kappa')$ and let $M_y$ be the transitive collapse of $S_y$, with $\pi:S_y\to M_y$ being a $\in\!\!-\!\!\in$ isomorphism. $|S_y|<\kappa$ and $|M_y|<\kappa$.

Assume there is a $x'\in V$ with $\varphi(x',y)$. Then there is $x\in S_y$ with $\varphi(x,y)$. Since $S_y$ is an elementary substructure of $H(\kappa')$, it is a model of ZF without powerset axiom and $\varphi^{S_y}(x,y)$ holds, because $\varphi$ is absolute. Because $\pi$ is a isomorphism and its restriction to the transitive set $T_y$ is the identity, $\varphi^{M_y}(\pi(x),y)$ holds. Because $M_y$ is isomorphic to $S_y$, ZF without powerset is true in $M_y$ and therefore $\varphi(\pi(x),y)$.

Now $TC(\{M_y\})=\{M_y\}\cup M_y$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$, so $M_y\in H(\kappa)$. Because $H(\kappa)$ is transitive and $\pi(x)\in M_y$, $\pi(x)\in H(\kappa)$.

Comment: This is "morally correct" but not quite formal. There are several problems. The first is that in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we cannot really form elementary substructures of the whole universe, so $S_y$ may not be defined. The second is that there may be many $x$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$, so you cannot simply conclude that $x\in S_y$. Besides the mathematical problems, a notational advice: Purely for clarity's sake, avoid using $H_y$, as $H(\kappa)$ already means something else.

Comment: All this can be fixed easily: Assume $\exists x\,\varphi(x,y)$. First, pick an $H(\lambda)$ with $\lambda>\kappa$ regular, large enough so there is some $x\in H(\lambda)$ with $\varphi(x,y)$ and therefore $\varphi^{H(\lambda)}(x,y)$. Now use this instead of $V$ when defining $S_y$. Note that $H(\lambda)$ satisfies $\exists t\,\varphi(t,y)$, so the same holds in its elementary substructure $S_y$. This means that in $S_y$ there is an $\hat x$ such that $\varphi^{S_y}(\hat x,y)$, etc. That $\hat x$ may be different from the $x$ we began with is irrelevant.

Comment: I have a question regarding "cannot form elementary substructure of V", if you don't mind. Trying to form a Skolem hull for a set $X$, if there is $x\in V$ with $\varphi(x,y_1,..,y_k)$ for $y_i\in X$, choose $\alpha$ so that x is in $V_{\alpha}$. Since X is a set, there is $\alpha$ so that this works for all $\varphi$ and parameters in $X$ at the same time. Then wellorder $V_{\alpha}$ and choose the smallest element for each such $\varphi$, $y_i$. Take $X_1$ as the set of those elements. Repeat this, get sets $X_i\subset X_{i+1}$, the union ($i<\omega$) should be an elem. substructure of V.

Comment: I see this shouldn't work because it would let ZFC prove its consistency, but I don't see the mistake in the argument at the moment.

Comment: This is a subtle issue. To formalize it, you need to define a satisfaction predicate, but this is not possible (say, because of Tarski's undefinability of truth theorem). This is discussed in Chapter 12 of Jech's **Set theory**, or see Kunen's **The foundations of mathematics**.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answers.

Comment: I think I fixed everything now.

Comment: Looks fine now.